# Is there a way to determine which external assembly methods are being used in a Powershell module?

Tags: powershell

I currently have a Powershell module that references several external assemblies. Is there a way, other than manually reviewing the module, to determine which methods from those external assemblies are being used? I have a set of Pester unit tests for this module, and I would like to ensure that all external dependencies are being tested.

Comment: hello,what's your mean you want reverse engendering the command exist in powershell ? if you want because all powershell use .net frame work use .net reflector get you all assemblies and etc...

Comment: I am trying to identify which methods contained in the external assemblies are being used by my Powershell module.

Comment: Is your module a binary module?

Comment: @dan-gph - the module is a script module (.psm1). I am able to manually read the script module to identify external function calls, but I was wondering if there was another way to do this using a command or utility.

Comment: There is a command. It is called `Select-String`. Use it like this: `Select-String '\[.+\]::'  MyModule.psm1`

Answer (score 0):

You say you have a PowerShell Module you are trying to examine.

If the PS module is a script module (.psm1), you can examine the script contents and trace each command.

Use Get-Command command to find out, which DLL is a command located in.

```
get-command test-path | fl DLL
DLL : C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad
  364e35\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management.dll
```

Use Trace-Command to examine dependencies.

```
Trace-Command –Name CommandDiscovery –Expression {Your code here..} -PSHost
```

Using * as a Name parameter will display all information.

```
Trace_Command -Name *
```

Good starting reference can be found here [Trace Your Commands by Using Trace-Command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/12/04/trace-your-commands-by-using-trace-command.aspx)

In your comments you mentioned that you were trying to trace the statement

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath)
```

Because this is not a PowerShell command, but a direct call to .NET dll method, the above approach is not going to work.

You will have to examine .NET assemblies using "Reflector" software. There are a number of those, I personally like [ILSpy](http://www.ilspy.net/) which is free.

The same applies to PS binary modules (DLL). Use "Reflector" software to open, decompile and examine the DLL.

Comment: This seems to only list Powershell cmdlets and functions. Is there any way to get it to list calls to functions that reside in a referenced assembly / dll ? I have tried the command with various -Name arguments so far with no success.

Comment: Do you have an example what you are looking for, or what command you're trying to trace?

Comment: For example, `Trace-Command -Name * -Expression { Test-Path $filePath [System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath) } -PSHost` will only show the call to Test-Path and not `[System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath)`   I am looking to get the call to `[System.IO.File]::Exists($filePath)` or any other external function.

Comment: Have you tried putting a semicolon ";" between the two commands you are tracing?

Comment: Yes, I apologize for the copy paste mistake. Both commands are being executed, and I do get a valid output on the console for each command.